# How to create new tab that has style as Description tab for Stock Items?

Tags: customization, acumatica

I want to create new tab (Software Solution) and add new field (Solution) that is the same as Description tab to allow users put some description.

[image]

This is what I have done.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the PXRichTextEdit control to achieve that. The customization design will not allow you to pick this control type, so you will likely need to manually edit the ASPX file directly to add a PXRichTextEdit. From the layout editor, select Actions->Edit Aspx, and manually modify the ASPX to add your new control. You can then click the Generate Customization Script button to update the customization project.

This is how the Description tab looks like in the ASPX:

```
            <px:PXTabItem Text="Description" LoadOnDemand="true" >
                <Template>
                    <px:PXRichTextEdit ID="edMyField" runat="server" DataField="UsrMyField">
                        <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinHeight="216" />
                    </px:PXRichTextEdit>
                </Template>
            </px:PXTabItem>
```

The underlying database field needs to a nvarchar(max) field and the DAC property needs to be decorated with the PXDBText(IsUnicode=true) attribute. If you use PXDBString, the content will not save.

Unfortunately, the database schema tool included with Customization Projects does not allow you to add nvarchar(max) fields (the maximum length supported is 4000) and this is not enough. You can use the following T-SQL script instead and add it to the customization project:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   sys.columns 
  WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Contact]') 
         AND name = 'UsrMyField'
)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contact] ADD [UsrMyField] nvarchar(max)
END
```

Comment: that's great! Thanks for the help.

Comment: But why when I save it, it's disappeared from that place?

Comment: When you save what?

Comment: it's okay now. Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with more details