# How to add a memo / formatted text field ala Cases

Tags: acumatica

I'd like to add a tab to a screen which contains a memo / formatted text area the way the Cases screen does, e.g.:

[image]

Adding a tab is straightforward, no help necessary there, but I don't remember seeing anything about how to add this type of text area in the training courses.  If there's an example I'd appreciate a point in the right direction.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628357/how-to-create-new-tab-that-has-style-as-description-tab-for-stock-items/38638504#38638504 should be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the RichTextEditor **manually** to your aspx file.

```
 <px:PXTabItem Text="Test">
    <Template>
      <px:PXRichTextEdit runat="server" AllowLoadTemplate="false" 
         AllowAttached="true" AllowSearch="true" AllowMacros="true" 
         AllowSourceMode="true" DataField="YOURFIELD" ID="edDescription" 
         Style='width:100%;'>
        <AutoSize Enabled="True" />
      </px:PXRichTextEdit>
    </Template>
</px:PXTabItem>
```

Make sure you Tab has the correct **Datamember** where your field used on the RichTextEditor is located.

```
 <px:PXTab DataMember="Document" ID="tab" runat="server" Height="540px" Style="z-index: 100;" Width="100%">
```

Also you could mark your Field used on the RichTextEditor as **PXDBText**.

```
    #region YourField
    public abstract class yourField : IBqlField { }

    protected String _yourField;
    [PXDBText(IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "YOURFIELD")]
    public virtual String YourField
    {
        get
        {
            return this._yourField;
        }
        set
        {
            this._yourField = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```