# How can I add a rich text box such as in the details tab in the Cases (CR306000) screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen where I want to add a tab containing a rich text box, ala the Cases (CR306000) screen's 'Detail' tab (shown below).

[image]

Not sure where in the database this information is stored, or whether that control is available for custom screens.  Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to px:PXRichTextEdit, there is also pxa:PXRichTextEdit as shown in the sample below bound to DataField "Contract", nvarchar(max):

```
        <pxa:PXRichTextEdit ID="edContract" runat="server" 
            Style="z-index: 113; border-width: 0px;"
            DataField="Contract" Width="800" Height="900">
            <ContentStyle BorderStyle="None" ></ContentStyle>
            <AutoSize Enabled="True" ></AutoSize>
        </pxa:PXRichTextEdit>
```

Ensure the Tab has the proper DataMember for your bound Field. The Field in the DAC can be:   [PXDBText(IsUnicode = true)]

See also this answer:  [How to add a memo / formatted text field ala Cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46471393/how-to-add-a-memo-formatted-text-field-ala-cases) and its further reference to Gabriel's answer therein.

From the layout editor, select Actions->Edit Aspx and manually modify the ASPX. You can then click the Generate Customization Script button to update the customization project.